# Saving highscores in a Flappy Bird clone using json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a Flappy Bird clone.

I'm still kinda new to Pygame. I have watched a tutorial about json saving (as you can see).  I've tried to make everything work, which it is, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to save the high score value still.

The tutorial shown was on a clicker game. I followed along, but a clicker game is different to saving a high score on a Flappy Bird clone and displaying it. I've tried to do what the tutorial says about displaying the amount saved, but it didn't work.

The code:

```py
import pygame, sys, random
import json

def draw_floor():
    screen.blit(floor_surface,(floor_x_pos,900))
    screen.blit(floor_surface,(floor_x_pos + 576,900))

def create_pipe():
    random_pipe_pos = random.choice(pipe_height)
    bottom_pipe = pipe_surface.get_rect(midtop = (584,random_pipe_pos))
    top_pipe = pipe_surface.get_rect(midbottom = (584,random_pipe_pos -300))
    return bottom_pipe,top_pipe

def move_pipes(pipes):
    for pipe in pipes:
        pipe.centerx -= 5
    visible_pipes = [pipe for pipe in pipes if pipe.right > -50]
    return visible_pipes

def draw_pipes(pipes):
    for pipe in pipes:
        if pipe.bottom >= 1024:
            screen.blit(pipe_surface,pipe)
        else:
            flip_pipe = pygame.transform.flip(pipe_surface,False,True)
            screen.blit(flip_pipe,pipe)

def check_collision(pipes):
    global can_score
    
    for pipe in pipes:
        if bird_rect.colliderect(pipe):
            hit_sound.play()
            can_score = True
            return False

        if bird_rect.top <= -100 or bird_rect.bottom >= 900:
            can_score = True
            hit_sound.play()
            return False

    return True

def rotate_bird(bird):
    new_bird = pygame.transform.rotozoom(bird,-bird_movement * 3,1)
    return new_bird

def bird_animation():
    new_bird = bird_frames[bird_index]
    new_bird_rect = new_bird.get_rect(center = (100,bird_rect.centery))
    return new_bird,new_bird_rect

# Data
data = {
    'highscore': 0
    }
try:
    with open('highscore.txt') as highscore_file:
        data = json.load(highscore_file)
except:
    print('No file')

def score_display(game_state):
    if game_state == 'main_game':
        score_surface = game_font.render(str(int(score)),True,(255,255,255))
        score_rect = score_surface.get_rect(center = (288,100))
        screen.blit(score_surface,score_rect)
    if game_state == 'game_over':
        score_surface = game_font.render(f'Score: {int(score)}',True,(255,255,255))
        score_rect = score_surface.get_rect(center = (288,100))
        screen.blit(score_surface,score_rect)

        high_score_surface = game_font.render(f'High score: {int(high_score)}',True,(255,255,255))
        high_score_rect = high_score_surface.get_rect(center = (288,850))
        screen.blit(high_score_surface,high_score_rect)

def update_score(score,high_score):
    if score > high_score:
        high_score = score
    return high_score

def pipe_score_check():
    global score, can_score
    
    if pipe_list:
        for pipe in pipe_list:
            if 95 < pipe.centerx < 105 and can_score:
                score += 1
                point_sound.play()
                can_score = False
                if pipe.centerx < 0:
                    can_score = True

# pygame.mixer.pre_init(frequency = 44100, size = 16, channels = 1, buffer = 512)
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((576,1024))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
game_font = pygame.font.Font('04B_19.ttf',40)

# Variables
gravity = 0.25
bird_movement = 0
game_active = True
score = 0
high_score = 0
can_score = True

# Loading images
bg_surface = pygame.image.load('assets/background-day.png').convert()
bg_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(bg_surface)

floor_surface = pygame.image.load('assets/base.png').convert()
floor_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(floor_surface)
floor_x_pos = 0

bird_downflap = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('assets/yellowbird-downflap.png').convert_alpha())
bird_midflap = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('assets/yellowbird-midflap.png').convert_alpha())
bird_upflap = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('assets/yellowbird-upflap.png').convert_alpha())
bird_frames = [bird_downflap,bird_midflap,bird_upflap]
bird_index = 0
bird_surface = bird_frames[bird_index]
bird_rect = bird_surface.get_rect(center = (100,512))

BIRDFLAP = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(BIRDFLAP,200)

# bird_surface = pygame.image.load('assets/yellowbird-midflap.png').convert_alpha()
# bird_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(bird_surface)
# bird_rect = bird_surface.get_rect(center = (100,512))

pipe_surface = pygame.image.load('assets/pipe-green.png').convert()
pipe_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(pipe_surface)

pipe_list = []

SPAWNPIPE = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(SPAWNPIPE,1500)
pipe_height = [400,600,800]

game_over_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('assets/message.png').convert_alpha())
game_over_rect = game_over_surface.get_rect(center = (288,512))

# Sounds
flap_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound/sfx_wing.wav')
hit_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound/sfx_hit.wav')
point_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound/sfx_point.wav')
countdown_sound_score = 100

# Event loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            with open('highscore.txt','w') as highscore_file:
                json.dump(data,highscore_file)
            
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and game_active:
                bird_movement = 0
                bird_movement -= 12
                flap_sound.play()
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and game_active == False:
                game_active = True
                pipe_list.clear()
                bird_rect.center = (100,512)
                bird_movement = 0
                score = 0
                
        if event.type == SPAWNPIPE:
            pipe_list.extend(create_pipe())

        if event.type == BIRDFLAP:
            if bird_index < 2:
                bird_index += 1
            else:
                bird_index = 0

            bird_surface,bird_rect = bird_animation()

# Pasting background image
    screen.blit(bg_surface,(0,0))
    
    if game_active:
# Bird movement and pasting bird
        bird_movement += gravity
        rotated_bird = rotate_bird(bird_surface)
        bird_rect.centery += bird_movement
        screen.blit(rotated_bird,bird_rect)
        game_active = check_collision(pipe_list)

# Pipes
        pipe_list = move_pipes(pipe_list)
        draw_pipes(pipe_list)
# Score
        pipe_score_check()
        score_display('main_game')
    else:   
        screen.blit(game_over_surface,game_over_rect)
        high_score = update_score(score,high_score)
        score_display('game_over')
                      
# Floor movement and pasting floor image
    floor_x_pos -= 1
    draw_floor()
    if floor_x_pos <=-576:
        floor_x_pos = 0
    
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```

Comment: 1. Reading data from and writing data to a JSON has nothing to do with pygame. 2. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary** to reproduce it in the question itself."* - this is way too much code, this is not the shortest code needed to reproduce the problem

Comment: 1. I imported pygame, so it does have to do with pygame, thank you very much. 2. Like I said in the post, I'm new to this, so I post all the code so people understand it all. You could probably Ctrl+F the information needed in the code. :)

Comment: It is dealing with high scores. I think, personally, that it does concern pygame quite a bit. :)

Comment: That's the problem. I'm unsure on where I should change it, then display it. I'm unsure whether I should `data = high_score` or not. I'm new and I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize the `highscore` variable with the data from the dictionary:

```py
data = { 'highscore': 0 }
try:
    with open('highscore.txt') as highscore_file:
        data = json.load(highscore_file)
except:
    print('No file')
```

<s>`high_score = 0`</s>

```py
high_score = data.get('highscore', 0)
```

And you must create a dictionary with the new high score before writing the dictionary to the JSON file

```py
if score > highscore:
    with open('highscore.txt','w') as highscore_file:
        data = { 'highscore': score }
        json.dump(data, highscore_file)
```

Comment: @JoshSmith Yes, instead of `high_score = 0`

Comment: `high_score` is never displayed in your code. You'te display `score`, but not `highscore`.